# how to remove space between jsp include tag and form in JSP

Tags: jsp

How can I remove a blank space between my jsp include tab and my form tag?
Following is my code:

```
<jsp:include page="<%=header%>" flush="true">         
   <jsp:param name="id" value="1234"/>   
</jsp:include> 
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="<%=servletURL%>/page">
</form>
```

Above code give me the following outcome:

```
This is my Header

This is my data from form tag
```

Instead of this I would like to get the following outcome:

```
This is my Header
This is my data from form tag
```

I tried to put `<jsp:include>` tag in the `<form>` tag. This removes the space but all my javascripts did not get processed.

So yes, any idea how I can remove the space?

Thanks in advance for any possible help!

Comment: Rephrase your question please. What is that "removing spaced between include and form"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you can try these solutions. Hope it helps.

### `<jsp:include>` tag inside `<form>` tag

```
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="<%=servletURL%>/page">
<jsp:include page="<%=header%>" flush="true">         
<jsp:param name="id" value="1234"/>   
</jsp:include> 
</form>
```

### or CSS control

```
<form style="margin:0px;" name="frm" method="POST" action="<%=servletURL%>/page">
```

Comment: the first suggestion prevents javascript from processing. The second one works wonder! Thanks! :)